# how to use if else statement for radiobuttons in android

Tags: java, android

I'm having two `RadioGroups` in one `layout` and each `radiogroup` has three `radio buttons`. so how can i use `if else statement`.

[two `radiogroups` in  each group having three `radiobuttons`.when user **clicked** on one **radiobutton** then it will display correct answer.else wrong answer.][1]

Comment: for example radiobuttons is used in the quiz application.

Comment: for example english subject having 10 questions each question having three radio buttons

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a radiobutton is checked in a radiogroup in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992936/how-to-check-if-a-radiobutton-is-checked-in-a-radiogroup-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this to get the checked radiobutton from the radioGroup

```
RadioGroup g = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rBtnDigits);

switch (g.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
{
case R.id.rbtnButton1
//do something
break;

case R.id.rbtnButton2
//do something
break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use `if else`  statement. You can do it in the easy way.

```
 int radioButtonId = rbGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
 View radioButton = radioButtonGroup.findViewById(radioButtonId);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    button = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);

    rg.performClick();
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() { 

 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            int selected = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            pos = rg.indexOfChild(findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));

            switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "You have Clicked RadioButton 1",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "You have Clicked RadioButton 2",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "You have Clicked RadioButton 3",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "You have Clicked RadioButton 4",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: answer sahi hai ya galat ye bata??

Comment: it will give me error ..cannot resolve a symbol ischecked                                                    if(radioButton.isChecked())
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FeMale option selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }