# Prevent form submission if radio button isn't checked

Tags: android, radio-group

Working on an education android app. One provides answers through `EditText` input, radio buttons and `CheckBox`.

I want a check for the `RadioGroup` that when no `RadioButton` is clicked it will prompt the student and prevent submission. I succeeded in `EditText` but unsucessful for `RadioButton`.

```
public void checkEmptyButtons(View view){
  RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.myRg);
    if (rg.getCheckedRadioButton()==-1{

    // this is where I have a problem
    //I don't even know how to search on the                     //dev.anderoid site
        }
    }
```

That's where am stucked. Thanks in advance
.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How to check if a radioButton is checked in a radioGroup in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992936/how-to-check-if-a-radiobutton-is-checked-in-a-radiogroup-in-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a radiobutton is checked in a radiogroup in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992936/how-to-check-if-a-radiobutton-is-checked-in-a-radiogroup-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

you need radioGroup checked Change Listener:

```
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
              //here you will get callback everytime radio button is checked along with id. You can have boolean checked here to know if any of your radio button is checked


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` in stead of `getCheckedRadioButton()`.

```
if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
    //no radio buttons are checked
}
else {
    //any one of the radio buttons is checked
}
```